# How do I set up a random color in cocos2d (swift) sprites?

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create multiple sprites randomly appearing with different colors. Right now I have this code:

```
func setRandomColor() {
    let random = (Float(rand()) / Float(RAND_MAX))
    self.color = CCColor.init(red: random / 255, green: random / 255, blue: random / 255)
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting that to do? What is it doing that requires help?

Comment: It's only showing white and black colors

Comment: Yes. That is to be expected. What is the value of random? Also, what values are you passing into the colour function? (Trying to help you debug this. It's a very simple fix to a very simple problem).

Comment: I'm only calling the function. There's no other color function. In my MainScene, I call this function. Random the last time I used a breakpoint was .13

Comment: I'm expecting it to show all kinds of colors.

Comment: You are calling `CCColor.init` function... No? So, what do you expect it to do if you pass the number 13 into that function for the red, green and blue values?

Comment: I've actually changed the code a bit since the last time I posted because it worked better. I'm just using `CCColor(red: random / 255 green: random / 255 blue: random / 255 )`

Comment: I was trying to get random values between 0 and 255 so that every time there would be a unique RGB value. I don't want it to only pass in 13. I think I should mod instead, but random is still a value below 1.

Comment: Yeah, ok. So you set the value random to 35 for example. So what do you think will happen if you pass the value 35 into the CCColor function?

Comment: Look at your code. How many random values are you actually generating?

Comment: I'm also only passing in one random value. Maybe I need 3 random values? EDIT: I did that, and now it only shows white. Is it because it is evaluating to zero? If I take out `\ Float(RAND_MAX)` will it work maybe?

Comment: Cool. So generate three random values, one for red, one for green,one for blue. See what happens.

Comment: You need the random values to be between 0 and 255.

Comment: arc4random_uniform(256) would be one way of doing that.

Comment: Nice! I got a pink planet value, but the rest were white for some reason. I'll keep running it a few times to see what happens.

Comment: How do I cast that into an integer? EDIT: I need it to be float. It says its not convertible to float.

Comment: I'm on my iPad at the moment. Google it. It has been asked before.

Comment: I think it might need to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: well, yeah. The actual value has to be between 0 and 1 but you are dividing by 255.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks for the help.